# Python: Extract string from text

Tags: python, string

I have a text in the following format:

```
>>name of section a     keyword
#a  
some text
some text
some text
>>END_SECTION
>>name  section b     keyword
#a
some text
some text
some text
>>END_SECTION
continues...
```

The 'keyword' can be either pass, fail or warn.

I want to write a code that can get the following output:

```
name of section  keyword
```

The problem is I am very new to python and don't know how to extract a string from a text file when what would be the end marker (the keyword) can vary between three different words.

I tried using the # sign as end mark for the string, but it does not work. The code I tried is:

```py
class get_word(object):
   
  def get_sentences(self, name_section):
      with open(filename) as file_content:
        file_content.read().splitlines()
        for line in file_content:
            if name_section in line:
               start_line = file_content.index(line)
               end_line = file_content[start_line:].index('#')
               data = file_content[start_line:start_line + end_line]
               return data
```

I have imported the code to a different script and wrote this code:

```py
import get_word

for data in f.get_sentences('name_section_a'):
    print(data)
```

But gives the following error:

```py
ValueError: False is not in list
```

Is there a better way to do this? Could it be possible to use re.match() for example?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can the section block, i.e. `>>SECTION` be more than one line? if you're certain it can only be one line at most, you probably can just search for that line based on the start characters `>>`

Comment: Please post the full traceback. I don't see any line that could produce that error.

Comment: Why are you searching other lines for the `#` marker? The keyword is on the same line as the section name.

Comment: I thought about using the `>>` characters to search for the line, but they are also used at the end of the section, so I don't know how to extract only the line that I want. The `>>SECTION NAME keyword`,  is indeed always only one line though

Comment: If you're certain that there are 5 spaces `     ` that always separate a section name from a keyword, then this looks like a job where regex can also assist if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're doing with the code that searches for `#`. It has nothing to do with returning the `name of section keyword` line.

```
class get_word(object):
   
    def get_sentences(self, name_section):
        prefix = ">>" + name_section
        with open(filename) as file_content:
            for line in file_content:
                if line.startswith(prefix):
                    return line.strip()
```

This doesn't return a list, it just returns a single line, so there's no need for a loop in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex for this, it should certainly be possible, though you'll need to use something like negative lookahead `?!` to skip the lines like `>>END_SECTION` for example.

The following regex should capture both the section names and keywords in the section start lines:

```
^>>(?!END_SECTION)(.*)[ ]{5}(.+)$
```

You can try it out here on [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/COBJMq/1) as well. Note that the first captured group is the section name, and the second in is the matched keyword at the end of the line.

If you want, here's a Python example that can be used to test with. Note that I'm using `StringIO` which represents a file-like object.

```py
import re
from io import StringIO

file_contents = StringIO("""
>>name of section a     keyword
#a
some text
some text
some text
>>END_SECTION
>>name  section b     keyword
#a
some text
some text
some text
>>END_SECTION
continues...
""")

string = file_contents.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'^>>(?!END_SECTION)(.*)[ ]{5}(.+)$', flags=re.MULTILINE)

section_names = pattern.finditer(string)
for section in section_names:
    # section is a Match object, we can access attributes like the matched
    # groups from the object.
    print(section.groups())
```

Output:

```
('name of section a', 'keyword')
('name  section b', 'keyword')
```

If you go with a *non-regex* solution, the following approach should also work:

```py
string = file_contents.read()
lines = string.strip().split('\n')

# separator between section name and keyword
sep = '     '

section_lines = [line.lstrip('>').split(sep, 1) for line in lines
                 if line.startswith('>>') and line[2:5] != 'END']

print(section_lines)
```

Prints:

```
[['name of section a', 'keyword'], ['name  section b', 'keyword']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact output you expect is unclear, but you can use a regex to extract the field:

```
import re

re.findall('(?<=^>>)(?!END_SECTION)(.*)', text, re.M)
```

Output:

```
['name of section a     keyword', 'name  section b     keyword']
```

###### if you want to separate the keyword and remove the number:

```
re.findall('(?<=^>>)(?!END_SECTION)(.*)\s+\w+\s+(\w+)', t, re.M)
```

Output:

```
[('name of section', 'keyword'), ('name  section', 'keyword')]
```

Input:

```
text = '''>>name of section a     keyword
#a  
some text
some text
some text
>>END_SECTION
>>name  section b     keyword
#a
some text
some text
some text
>>END_SECTION'''
```